# Python; BeautifulSoup and inbuilt Functions

Tags: python, function, beautifulsoup

I'm currently having some trouble with the use of BeautifulSoup, and was wondering if there is a work around, as I wasn't exactly sure how to search for this problem.

I am currently parsing data from an E-mail by using the BeautifulSoup module with Python. You are able to do the following:

```
>>> soup.title.string
>>> 'The string found withing the Title Tags'
```

However, the current problem is that I would like to extract the information between the `<from>` tags.

Therefore, when typing the following:

```
>>> soup.from.string
```

Python recognizes `from` as an inbuilt function, and therefore I am unable to get this to work. Is there a way to get Python to recognize from as part of the Module's function, rather than it's own in-built function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`soup.find(tagName)`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) in this case. For example, that `from` tag:

```
soup.find('from').string
```

---

And if you have more `from` tags in your HTML file, [`soup.find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) would be a better choose. It returns a list of all of the `from` tags when you're searching `from`, etc:

```
soup.find_all('from')[2].string    # get the string in the third `from` tag
```

We also have `soup.find_next()` and `soup.find_parents()`. To understand the usage of them, check the document which I linked.

---

Here's a simple demo about them:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup("""
... <html>
...     <head>
...     </head>
...     <body>
...         <from>The first `from` tag</from>
...         <from>The second `from` tag</from>
...         <from>The third `from` tag</from>
...     </body>
... </html>""", "html.parser")

>>> soup.find('from').string
'The first `from` tag'

>>> soup.find_all('from')
[<from>The first `from` tag</from>,
 <from>The second `from` tag</from>,
 <from>The third `from` tag</from>]

>>> soup.find_all('from')[2].string
'The third `from` tag'
>>>
```

Comment: @DeanHenry: If you think this answer of mine is helpful, please accept it. Check our [tour] for more details.